# Error converting dataframe to netcdf file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, netcdf

I want to convert a dataframe with variables: time, latitude, longitude and some brightness temperatures. I use this function:

```
df.to_netcdf(path='/home/hamid/dataAMSR.nc4', mode='a', format=None, group=None, engine="netcdf4", encoding=None, unlimited_dims=None, compute=True, invalid_netcdf=False)
```

But, it return this error: `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'to_netcdf'`

Comment: What have you imported? is xarray in there? Please note: without full code it is difficult for people to figure out what is wrong

Answer (score 0):

You have to use e.g. xarray to write a netcdf4 file. So intall [netcdf4](https://pypi.org/project/netCDF4/) and [xarray](https://pypi.org/project/xarray/) and go on with the following line:

```
xarray.Dataset(df.to_xarray()).to_netcdf('/home/hamid/dataAMSR.nc4')
```

Otherwise you have to tell us the package that enables `to_netcdf` feature for DataFrames because this feature is not supported by pandas at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

**dl.meteo**! it works like a charm, i should just have the dataframe variables in the following order: time, latitude, longitude and others variables.
**Many thanks to you**!
Cheers
Hamid